# tensorflow issue in Python 3.9

Tags: python, tensorflow

im  using the below packages but somehow im getting the below error:

```
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
```

Error:

```
2020-10-18 23:50:57.727315: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll
 not found
2020-10-18 23:50:57.729741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "C:\Users\sayan\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main error occurs due to missing module `tensorflow.contrib`. I believe `tflearn` may have that as a dependency. Newer versions of tensorflow (>2.0) does not include contrib module.

You may be able to resolve the issue by upgrading `tflearn` to the latest version. As per their docs TF2.0 is supported now. ([Installation instructions here](http://tflearn.org/installation/#using-latest-tensorflow))

Other than that you have a warning (W) and information (I) provided by `tensorflow`.

1. Warning states that it is not able to access cuda files for GPU support.
2. Information says you can ignore the warning if you are not using GPU.

Do you wish to use tensorflow with GPU support? This may require installation of cuda and other dependencies.